# worker.recognize(...).progress is not a function. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express

my code is:

```js
    //Imports
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const fs = require("fs");
    const multer = require('multer');
    const { createWorker } = require("tesseract.js");
    const worker = createWorker();

    //Storage
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req,file,cb) => {
        cb(null, "./uploads");
    },
    filename: (req,file,cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
    });
    const upload = multer({storage: storage}).single("avatar");

    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    //route
    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
       res.render('index');
    });

    app.post('/upload',(req,res) => {
        upload(req,res, err => {
            fs.readFile(`./uploads/${req.file.originalname}`,(err,data) => {
                if(err) return console.log('This is your error',err);

             worker
                .recognize(data, "eng", {tessjs_create_pdf: '1'})
                .progress(progress => {
                    console.log(progress);
                })
                .then(result => {
                    res.send(result.text);
                })
                .finally(() => worker.terminate())
             });
         });
     });

     //Start Up our server
     const PORT = 5000 || process.env.PORT;
     app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Hey I am running on port ${PORT}`));
```

the error I get is this

```
     D:\ML\OCR\app.js:34
                    .progress(progress => {
                     ^

    TypeError: worker.recognize(...).progress is not a function
        at D:\ML\OCR\app.js:34:18
```

I know worker.recognize/.progress is decapitated but can someone please correct this code.
Thank you.

I am trying to create an OCR using tesseract.js . watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1I3tcALTlc

But I am not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Change this line

```
const worker = createWorker();
```

To

```
const worker = await createWorker();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the code is out of date.

Try this

```
            async function getTextFromImage() {
            await worker.load()
            await worker.loadLanguage('eng')
            await worker.initialize('eng')
            const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize(data);
            
                
            res.send(text);
            console.log(text);
            await worker.terminate()
            
            }
            
            getTextFromImage();
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32539063)